# Background music in windows phone 8 SDK [C#]

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-music

i am developing an app , and i need to put a song that plays when the app starts

Am using Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone 8

How i can do that?

Comment: Any specific question other than *How i can do that*? Because It implies *I haven't tried anything and expect someone to write whole code for me*.

Comment: @L.B how i can start writing code if i don't know anything about Background Music ? 
That's why i came here , for help , I need the way and i will do the rest

Comment: Then you are on the wrong site. because it is not a specific problem about actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the windows phone audio playback agent. check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) out